# Docker layer info post v1.10

Tags: hash, docker

I used to check the sizes of layers in an image using the Docker history command, although now that shows "missing" instead of layer IDs due to the 1.10 migration to content hashes.

I now retrieve the hashes of all layers in an image through these commands:

```
docker pull ubuntu
ID=$(docker inspect -f {{.Id}} ubuntu)
sudo jq .rootfs.diff_ids /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/imagedb/content/$(echo $ID|tr ':' '/')
```

This returns a list of content hashes of all layers in the ubuntu image:

```
"diff_ids": [
  "sha256:2a4049cf895d2384cb93d19f46f0d62560a48b2b202787edad2dc6e4b95a923a",
  "sha256:01fbb4b5fa1b76ccdc289de098ea61925c7f8d3364159761720617b096f27bcc",
  "sha256:d3492de15d7c87ea9db9ab123214d334f4bcb1e40846b77beebb4c37dd134a45",
  "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
],
```

In /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/ I see information about each layer such as parent and size but I noticed that the diff_ids in this folder are not the same as the above output:

```
> ls /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/
2088e4744016dbe95308d1920060f1fbc4a095ba5b9517d758745fc3986f2632
2a4049cf895d2384cb93d19f46f0d62560a48b2b202787edad2dc6e4b95a923a
8c63d05abe660a2f3f04d754de3ee3d927a17b3623a8e2be6d727e697f4b1e10
f747ac597de13b7f1ff918874f80bb83004232d7d6d4d45ad8890b58cdc79adc
```

I then tried inspecting another folder such as /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers:

```
> ls /var/lib/docker/aufs/layers#
58e7ed1f6d4ba047c9c714e66f10c014008ef4aa133d334198b8b1b7673f16e7
c4dd5a81188e36457624849aaeea74d98ef571390db75d4a03efb5bccb8c04e3
d31f918b7f59fcf768a9ae609141152cd5ae63943aac042429e3d2e04d472bcc
e576c6d41b96bd6a47233a6c6ec2f586021aa945aae6bd0e73ab9d4ad051a94e
```

As you can see these are 4 other content hashes again. Can someone tell me what the connection is between all these hashes and how I can find the size of each layer of the Ubuntu image? I'd like to be able to match each diff_id in the first output with a size but I don't know how all these diff_ids in different folders are related.

EDIT: I solved it like this - /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/ also contains a file called "diff" which contains the diff_id corresponding to the output of the first command. I used this output to map the size to the correct diff_id.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this: /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/ also contains a file called "diff" which contains the diff_id corresponding to the output of the first command. I used this output to map the size to the correct diff_id.